# Convert day into date

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to find a way to convert a column in a pandas dataframe that contains the day of month (1, 2, .. 30) into a datetime. The year and month are static (for example, always November 2014) and are NOT contained in the data frame.

**Example:**

day=13 gets converted to November 13, 2014.

day=27 gets converted to November 27, 2014.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with convert column to string and add years with month:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'day':[13,27,9,4,2,3]})

df['day'] = pd.to_datetime('2014-01-' + df['day'].astype(str))
```

Or use parameter `origin` with `unit`, but is necessary subtract 1:

```
df['day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['day'] - 1, unit='d', origin='2014-01-01')
```

---

```
print (df)
         day
0 2014-01-13
1 2014-01-27
2 2014-01-09
3 2014-01-04
4 2014-01-02
5 2014-01-03
```